# How to plot speed heatmap in python

Tags: python

I'm relatively new to python, familiar with basic syntax and know how to import certain libraries but other than that - total newbie
Recently, I encountered with the problem where I needed to plot speed heatmap of a truck.

I have following data (columns):
Date  Speed  Longitude  Latitude

Is it possible to plot speed heatmap of a truck so that it's geographically referenced and it would be visible at which points truck slowed down and vice versa?
I wanted to use Power Query in Excel to prepare my data for analysis but unfortunately CSV file is too large for Excel to handle
Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the data in a dictionary:

```py
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('example.csv')

lons = np.array(data['Longitude'])
lats = np.array(data['Latitude'])
speed = np.array(data['Speed'])

plt.figure(figsize = (14, 12))
plt.title('Truck Speed')
plt.xlabel('Longitude')
plt.ylabel('Latitude')
plt.scatter(lons, lats, c = speed)
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.set_label('Speed')
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I'm really sorry for stupid question, how do I load my CSV data?

Comment: @MDoskarin in your python file at the top `import csv` then `data = csv.reader(your_file, delimiter='')`

Comment: What if my CSV is already divided into columns and my GPS column data is the only one containing ":" delimeter?

Comment: There are no stupid questions - just stupid people that don't ask questions.